# iOS export call logs to csv/excel or similar file in app

Tags: ios, cocoa, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I know that I cannot read directly from the call_history.db, but I know that itunes can export the call logs onto a mac, and several other programs can do this to PC or osx.

Is there any sort of framework or API that would let me export the db to an excel or csv while the app is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Only if the phone is jail broken.